# Sunset schedule for legacy database secrets

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I maintain a library for Google Apps Script that provides an interface and generation of custom authentication tokens.  I've already transitioned over to generation of tokens from a service account instead of the project secrets.

I still see you can get the project secret token even in new firebase projects. Is there a sunset schedule for these? Can users of the library continue to use project secrets or should I start encouraging transition to only using service accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Legacy database token will be shut down on March 15th, 2017 with legacy dashboard.
>
> You can still migrate to new console, but keep using old SDK and use new tokens. When you are ready to update your code, you can switch to new SDK.

Was the answer the Firebase Support team gave me today.